nodeMailer sends email when asked by one module, but not another
I am trying to send two sorts of emails from my website:

a randomly generated password sent to a user who asks for one (from module PayAsYouLike), and
a get-in-touch form that sends the email to my personal account so I can read it (from module GetInTouch).

Now, I am using the exact same router file called 'email.js' to send both kinds of emails. However, 100% of the time, (2) works and the email goes through, but 100% of the time (1) doesn't and the console logs a "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error. I can't be more clearer: the endpoint aka email.js works perfectly well for both 1) and 2) when tested through Thunder client. However, as soon as the front-end makes the call, 1) doesn't work but 2) always does.
I am adding the 'email.js' router code here and just remember that on the server side console, it only gets as far as the console.log inside the sendMail function that says 'Inside sendMail, but before transporter.sendMail call!'. That puts the error somewhere inside the transporter.sendMail(mailOptions) call. REMEMBER: all of this works perfectly well when email.js is used to send the form from GetInTouch.
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
require("dotenv").config();
const nodeMailer = require("nodemailer");

router.route("/").post((req, res) => {
  const form = req.body;
  let mailOptions = {};

  console.log(form);

  const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.USER,
      pass: process.env.APP_PASSWORD,
    },
  });

  if ("password" in form) {
    const passwordDate = new Date(form.date);
    const passwordValidity = new Date(passwordDate.getTime() + 172800000);
    const options = { 
      year: 'numeric', 
      month: 'long', 
      day: 'numeric', 
      hour: 'numeric', 
      minute: 'numeric', 
      second: 'numeric',
      hour12: true 
    };

    mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.USER,
      to: form.email,
      subject: "Your PASSWORD is here!",
      html: `Dear ${
        form.name || form.email
      }, <br><br>Your PASSWORD: <h3 style="display:inline;">${
        form.password
      }</h3><br><i>Expiry:</i> <h4 style="display:inline;">${passwordValidity.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options)}</h4>`,
    };
  } else {
    mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.USER,
      to: "karangour@gmail.com",
      subject: "GetInTouch form",
      html: `FROM: ${form.name}<br>EMAIL: ${form.email}<br>SUBJECT: ${form.subject}<br>MESSAGE: ${form.message}`,
    };
  }
  console.log("Mail options prepared:", mailOptions);

  const sendMail = async (transporter, mailOptions) => {
    try {
      console.log('Inside sendMail, but before transporter.sendMail call!')
      await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
      console.log("Email has been sent successfully!!");
      res.json({
        status: "Success",
        message: "Email sent successfully",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.json({
        status: "Error",
        message: "Failed to send email",
        error: error.message,
      });
    }
  };

  sendMail(transporter, mailOptions);
});

module.exports = router;


I've done everything, from making two seperate router files, or using a callback function in App.jsx to update a state variable object that I can use to let PayAsYouLike use the fetch of GetInTouch to send its password through email, but somehow, React/Express knows that this is a object coming in from PayAsYouLike and creates the connection refused error.

If the issue always happens in the statement - await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions), then the object mailOptions may be the suspect.  Since it has been compiled differently in the two options. The same transporter has been created for option 1 and option 2, therefore there can be no point of failure in the transporter.
However when tested through the User-agent - Thunder Client, it does not fail, which means mailOptions compiled correctly in either cases. Then we need to suspect the User-agent as well. It means when the User-agent is a browser, then mailOptions compiled for option 1 has something to fail.
The summary is when the option 1 is invoked from the front-end (via browser), then the mailOptions compiled has some issues.
Request, please execute console.log of the object mailOpions under the following two cases, and check for any differences.
1. Option 1 and the User-agent - Thunder Client
2. Again for Option 1 and the User-agent - browser


Thanks for the response. So I managed to find a way to make it work and you’re right - mailOptions compile is the problem. So instead of compiling it on the server, I did it on the front end and then sent it to the email router with mailOptions looking exactly the same as option 2 with just the password and a few more properties attached. This is less secure as the password is going back to the front end after creation in the back end and then sent back to the server, but it isn’t a very important password so will suffice for now. Thanks again.

Thanks for the update. Glad to hear the issue resolved. Questioning ourselves and finding alternates are good. We will become more pragmatic and progressing.
